# Why does flash drives app in stack? CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH Camera2API

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, ip-camera, camera-flash

There is weird situation. I took [standard google sample `camera2API`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).

I need that flash is worked permanently, regardless of outside light.

In order to accomplish it i have changed one line of code:

```
private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (mFlashSupported) {
//            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
    }
}
```

It was `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH` i have changed it to `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH`.

And i have faced with issue, when i click <kbd>Take picture</kbd> button, camera is flashing and that is it. App goes to stack...

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I figure out next:

i have tryed tern on flash on three different device `Meizu MX5`, `Samsung S5` and `Samsung S6`.

Two of them `Meizu MX5`, `Samsung S5` work correctly with code above and app doesn't drives in stack.

Problem occur with `Samsung S6`, BUT ...

Method `setAutoFlash()` invokes within code 3 times in different places

1. `captureStillPicture()`
2. `unlockFocus()`
3. `onConfigured()`

And trick is if i disable `setAutoFlash()` in `captureStillPicture()` for `Samsung S6` it is stop stacking and flash begins to works but if i try this approach for `Meizu MX5`, `Samsung S5` flash doesn't works...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37144657/6950238) question and [that](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JhfkgFaEFrUJ:crypto.nknu.edu.tw/AOSP/Android6/cts/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/CaptureRequestTest.java+&cd=10&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua) example.

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko It is doesn't looks like that i need, but i have figured some intresting things... I have added them in question, maybe it can help to suspect something...

Comment: "It is doesn't looks like that i need" - I know that isn't answer and post that as comment with hope that You will find there something useful )

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko No, that guy has another issue... Anyway thanks!

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko i have posted answer how i solved my issue, could you please take a look and if you know the reason why i got this issue let  me know)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i found solution

As i said method

```
protected final void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (isFlashSupported) {
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
    }
}
```

invoked in three different places in code.

1. `captureStillPicture()`
2. `unlockFocus()`
3. `onConfigured()`

So i implemented this line `requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);` locally in each method.

Finally that i get :

1. `unlockFocus()` ->
   `mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);`
2. `onConfigured()` ->
   `mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);`

and for this method remained auto settings

3. `captureStillPicture()` ->
   `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);`

But i don't know the reason why i got such issue... If someone know the reason please let me know.